# Open a text file or html file with a button click in MFC

Tags: visual-c++, button, mfc, dialogbasedapp

i have created dialog based MFC application with VS 2012 and want to open a text file window without the user having to browse it just like when we click a file it opens similarly in my application text file must be open when button is clicked.

thanks

Comment: And, you've tried what?  Your problem is......?

Comment: Do you want to start notepad or what do you mean with text file window? Is it always the same text file you want to open? Does your program know the text file's file name in advance?

Comment: Yes i want to start notepad and yes i always want to open the same text file stored at a particular location.

Comment: I think he/she wants a preview of the file on a Open File Dialog.